# Как подключить сразу несколько библиотек?

Tags: c++

Есть код, к которому нужно подключить огромное количество заголовочных файлов, которые лежат все в одной директории. Вопрос, есть ли в С++ механизм, который позволит это сделать сразу подключив всю директорию, а не прописывая `#inclide "..."` для всех хидеров отдельно?

Comment: Нет такого механизма.

Comment: Нет =( и не было никогда

Comment: И не будет, потому что бесполезно и даже вредно. Большие библиотеки обычно сами определяют что нужно подключать, а что нет. От такой возможности толку не будет, а будет просто больше вопросов на SO типа "не могу подключить библиотеку".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам придется создать еще один заголовочный файл и подключить в него все Ваши `#include "..."`руками. Но зато Вы в дальнейшем сможете подключать только этот общий хедер к другим проектам.

Comment: Кстати, #include <windows.h> вроде бы так и делает... Подключая огромную пачку стандартных заголовков.

Comment: Плюс есть замки от "повторного подключения" вроде `#ifndef file1_h #define file1_h .... #endif` Тогда библиотеки можно пачками хоть перекрестно подключать. Тоже в windows.h используется в дебрях.

Comment: Это крайне плохой совет. Каждый файл должен напрямую влючать все требующиеся ему заголовочные файлы. @zcorvid Нет, `windows.h` делает далеко не так.

Comment: @VTT Зачем напрямую? В Qt ,например, есть заголовочный файл QtGui, который включает все классы для работы с графикой, и Вам незачем все модули подключать отдельно. Да, это занимает больше памяти, чем отдельное подключение, но все же есть такая возможность.

Comment: @Konstantin_SH Неправильная аналогия. То обобщающий заголовок из библиотеки, а не самопальный.